# How can i group fields of a dimension in MDX query?

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2008-r2

I have Customer Dimension with these fields:
City
Cost
Date

Ex.:

```
[Customer].[City].&[London]
[Customer].[City].&[Paris]
[Customer].[City].&[Milano]
[Customer].[City].&[Firenze]
[Customer].[City].&[Madrid]
[Customer].[City].&[Berlin]
```

And I need to do this:

```
[Customer].[City].&[London] -> [Customer].[City_G].&A
[Customer].[City].&[Paris] -> [Customer].[City_G].&A
[Customer].[City].&[Milano] -> [Customer].[City_G].&A
[Customer].[City].&[Firenze] - [Customer].[City_G].&B
```

In the reporting service I need to show the group A and B, not only rename(I can do that with case statement) I need to show the total of London,Paris and Milano in the field A.

Can you help me? thanks!!

Comment: Have you considered handling this in datawarehouse? That would be the better thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used the tag `mdx` so in an `mdx` script these would be grouped like this:

```
WITH SET [set_A] AS
{
  [Customer].[City].&[London],
  [Customer].[City].&[Paris],
  [Customer].[City].&[Milano]
}
MEMBER [Customer].[City_G].[A] AS
  AGGREGATE([set_A]) 
SELECT
[Customer].[City_G].[A] ON 0,
[Measures].[somMeasure] ON 1
FROM [yourCube];
```

If counts or distinct counts are not required then `AGGREGATE` can be replaced with `SUM` in the above.